# CSS tooltip added with insertBefore() not always on top

Tags: css, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a tooltip to each event in a FullCalendar resource timeline. The problem is, that the tooltips are covered by other events nearby. I'm attaching two screenshots (tooltip covered/shown):

[image: Tooltip covered by event below]

[image: Tooltip shown correctly]

Here are the source files of the angular component (resource-timeline).

**resource-timeline.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-2" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="p-3">
          <full-calendar #resourceTimeline [options]="resourceTimelineOptions"></full-calendar>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**resource-timeline.component.scss**:

```
.timeline-tooltip {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 120px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;

  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  }
}
```

**resource-timeline.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {CalendarOptions, EventContentArg, FullCalendarComponent} from "@fullcalendar/angular"
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router'
import {EventHoveringArg} from "@fullcalendar/common"

@Component({
  selector: 'resource-timeline',
  templateUrl: './resource-timeline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resource-timeline.component.scss']
})
export class ResourceTimelineComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('fc-timeline-event.fc-event-start', {static: false}) calendarEvent: ElementRef
  toolTipDiv: ElementRef

  @ViewChild('resourceTimeline')
  calendar: FullCalendarComponent

  resourceTimelineOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    schedulerLicenseKey: "CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives",
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    height: window.innerHeight - 380,
    eventMinWidth: 5,
    titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'},
    plugins: [
      resourceTimelinePlugin
    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      center: 'resourceTimelineDay',
      right: 'prev,today,next'
    },
    resourceAreaColumns: [
      {
        headerContent: 'Bench Name',
        field: 'resourceName',
      },
      {
        headerContent: 'Description',
        field: 'description',
      }
    ],
    weekNumbers: true,
    firstDay: 1, // monday
    scrollTime: '07:00:00',
    selectable: false,
    selectMirror: false,
    selectOverlap: false,
    eventOverlap: false,
    editable: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    buttonText: {
      day: 'Day',
      week: 'Week',
      month: 'Month',
      today: 'Today'
    },
    eventDidMount: (eventInfo: EventContentArg) => {
    },
    eventMouseEnter: (eventInfo: EventHoveringArg) => {
      this.removeToolTip()
      this.insertToolTip(eventInfo.event.title, eventInfo.el)
    },
    eventMouseLeave: (eventInfo: EventHoveringArg) => {
      this.removeToolTip()
    }
  }

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              private domElement: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resourceTimelineOptions.resources = [
      {
        "id": "id1",
        "resourceName": "Resource 1",
        "description": "Description 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "resourceName": "Resource 2",
        "description": "Description 2"
      }
    ]

    this.resourceTimelineOptions.events = [
      {
        id: "id1",
        resourceId: "id1",
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2022-06-13'
      },
      {
        id: "id2",
        resourceId: "id2",
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2022-06-13',
        end: '2022-06-14'
      }
    ]
  }

  private insertToolTip(tooltipText: string, eventElement: HTMLElement): void {
    // Create ToolTipContent
    this.toolTipDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div')
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.toolTipDiv, 'class', 'timeline-tooltip')
    const text = this.renderer.createText(tooltipText)
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.toolTipDiv, text)
    this.renderer.insertBefore(eventElement, this.toolTipDiv, this.calendarEvent)
  }

  private removeToolTip(): void {
    if (this.toolTipDiv !== undefined) {
      const elements = this.domElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.timeline-tooltip')
      elements.forEach(e => {
        this.renderer.removeChild(e.parentElement, e)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried different values for position (relative, fixed, static) and different values for z-index, but none of the changes solve the issue directly.
Has anyone got a clue how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bootstrap included, you could use "eventContent" and inject the bootstrap tooltip element here.

Something like this:

```
eventContent: function(info, createElement) {
  return createElement('div', { 
    'data-bs-placement': 'auto', 
    'data-bs-toggle': 'tooltip', 
    'title': 'My tooltip'
  }, 'Event Content');
}
```

Maybe this example helps: https://codepen.io/sirsir1/pen/gOvVdae

For more infos on Fullcalendar's content injection checkout: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection